# Mutliple Tokens in Authorization Header

Tags: http, authorization, apigee

Can I add two bearer tokens in the Authorization Header for a request? If So how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely. "Authorization" can only handle one set of credentials. So if the "token" scheme can only carry one token at a time, the answer is "no".